# Unable to enter Text in a input TextBox using Javascriptexecutor

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Running into a peculiar problem where I am unable to enter text into a TextBox using Selenium.

I have tried the below approaches till now but unable to achieve the result with anyone of them :

1. SendKeys
2. Actions class
3. javascriptexecutor

Details About Page Section under Test:

1. Page section has two radio buttons which gives the option to user to follow different path for verification.
2. The Xpath of the field on which I am facing the issue remains same even when user selects any of the two Checkboxes which I think is possibly the issue.
3. This is not an issue related to frame switching as other fields in the section are working fine.

Result :

1. Code is able to Click on the field but not enter text.
2. Even if it enters the text 2 out of 5 times through javascriptexecutor, the page fails to recognize the text. As it is a mandatory field, error is thrown later even if text is populated through javascript.

Expectation :

Need a Robust way to make it work. Any approach would work.

Approach 1 : SendKeys

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@class='cPATCHEDOmniScriptCommunity']")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@ng-show='creditCheckDetails && !successCreditBoolVal']/div[2]/div[1]/input[1]")).sendKeys("TestData");
```

Approach 2 : Actions Class

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@class='cPATCHEDOmniScriptCommunity']")));
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@ng-show='creditCheckDetails && !successCreditBoolVal']/div[2]/div[1]/input[1]"))).sendKeys("TestData").build().perform();
```

Approach 3 : Javascriptexecutor

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@class='cPATCHEDOmniScriptCommunity']")));
    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    jse.executeScript("arguments[0].value='testdata';", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@ng-show='creditCheckDetails && !successCreditBoolVal']/div[2]/div[1]/input[1]")));
```

Approach 4 : Javascriptexecutor

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@class='cPATCHEDOmniScriptCommunity']")));
    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    jse.executeScript("document.evaluate(//div[@ng-show='creditCheckDetails && !successCreditBoolVal']/div[2]/div[1]/input[1], document, null, 9, null).singleNodeValue.innerHTML="+ BusinessName);
```

Page HTML :

```
<div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-size--1-of-1 slds-medium-size--6-of-6 slds-large-size--12-of-12 slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-grid_align-center tileContainer b-t-4" ng-class="{'b-t-4': creditCheckDetails, 'b-t-1': !creditCheckDetails}" ng-show="showCreditSectionForAgent" style="">
            <h2 class="titleHeader ng-binding">Business verification</h2>

            <div class="arrow_padding isMobile"><img src="/resource/vz_images/images/arrow.svg" class="tileIcon isMobile ng-hide" ng-click="completePlaceOrder = false; creditCheckDetailsMobile = true;scrollToTopOfPage();" ng-show="!creditCheckDetails &amp;&amp; !successCreditBoolVal &amp;&amp; showPlus" style=""></div>


            <img src="/resource/BuyflowImages/BuyflowImages/plus-large.svg" class="tileIcon isNotMobile ng-hide" ng-click="insatllationDetails = false; contactDetails = false; shippingAddressDetails = false; billingAddressDetails = false; termsAndConditionDetails = false; cardMessageCheck(); creditCardDetails = false; creditCheckDetails = !creditCheckDetails" ng-show="!creditCheckDetails &amp;&amp; !successCreditBoolVal &amp;&amp; showPlus" style="">

            <img src="/resource/BuyflowImages/BuyflowImages/minus-large.svg" class="tileIcon isNotMobile" ng-click="insatllationDetails = false; contactDetails = false; shippingAddressDetails = false; billingAddressDetails = false; termsAndConditionDetails = false; cardMessageCheck(); creditCheckDetails = !creditCheckDetails" ng-show="creditCheckDetails &amp;&amp; !successCreditBoolVal" style="">

            <div class="slds-size--1-of-1 ng-hide" ng-show="!creditCheckDetails &amp;&amp; !showHelpMessage" style="">

                <p class="Body warn-state" ng-show="!successCreditBoolVal">Please complete credit check.</p>
                <p class="Body warn-state ng-binding ng-hide" ng-show="creditCheckError"></p>
                <p class="Body success-state ng-hide" ng-show="successCreditBoolVal">Credit approval complete</p>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-size--1-of-1 vz_alert-warn helpMessage ng-binding ng-hide" ng-show="showHelpMessage &amp;&amp; !successCreditBoolVal" ng-bind-html="helpMessage"></div>
            <div class="slds-size--1-of-1" ng-show="creditCheckDetails &amp;&amp; !successCreditBoolVal" style="">
                <p class="Body">As part of your new service request, we need to do a standard business verification using your Federal Tax ID. If you do not have a Tax ID, we can use your personal information as well.</p>
                <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-size--1-of-1 slds-medium-size--6-of-6 slds-large-size--12-of-12 slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-grid_align-center creditCheckSolePCorpLLC" style="padding-top: 2%;">
                    <div class="slds-size--1-of-1">
                        <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-size--1-of-1 slds-medium-size--6-of-6 slds-large-size--8-of-12 slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-grid_align-center">

                            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-size--1-of-1 slds-medium-size--3-of-6 slds-large-size--6-of-12 slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-grid_align-center" style="padding-right: 10px;">
                                <label class="container-radio">
                                   <input type="radio" name="soleOrCorp" value="corporationLLC" ng-model="soleOrCorp" style="-webkit-appearance: radio;" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty">
                                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                <span for="contactChoice2" style="font-family: 'NeueHaasGroteskText'; font-size: 14px; color: black;">My Business uses a Federal Tax ID</span> 
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-size--1-of-1 slds-medium-size--3-of-6 slds-large-size--6-of-12 slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-grid_align-center">
                                <label class="container-radio">
                                    <input type="radio" name="soleOrCorp" value="soleproprietorship" ng-model="soleOrCorp" style="-webkit-appearance: radio;" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty">
                                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                <span style="font-family: 'NeueHaasGroteskText'; font-size: 14px; color: black;">My Business does not have a Federal Tax ID</span>
                                </label>
                            </div>


                            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-large-size--6-of-12"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>




                </div>
                <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-size--1-of-1 slds-medium-size--6-of-6 slds-large-size--12-of-12 slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-grid_align-center corpLLCSoleContainer" style="padding-top:1%;" ng-show="soleOrCorp === 'corporationLLC'">
                    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-size--1-of-1 slds-medium-size--3-of-6 slds-large-size--6-of-12 slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-grid_align-center" style="display: block;padding-right: 30px;">
                        <label class="labelAboveTextBox">Business name*</label>
                        <input type="text" class="businessName ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched" ng-model="businessName" ng-keyup="setBusinessName(businessName)" maxlength="30" style="width: 100%;">
                        <!-- ngIf: reqForBusinessName -->
                        <!-- ngIf: reqForBusinessNamesalphabets -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-size--1-of-1 slds-medium-size--3-of-6 slds-large-size--6-of-12 slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-grid_align-center" style="display: block;padding-right: 30px;">

                        <label class="labelAboveTextBox">Federal Tax ID*</label>
                        <input type="password" ng-required="businessTaxId" class="businessTaxId ng-pristine ng-empty ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched" ng-model="businessTaxId" ng-change="Check(businessTaxId, 'tId', 'businessTaxId')" ng-blur="PIEEncryptionTax()" ng-class="{'vz_error': businessTaxId.length > 0 &amp;&amp; businessTaxId.length !== 9, 'noredBorder': businessTaxId.length === 9}" style="width: 100%;">
                        <!-- ngIf: reqForBusinessTaxIDForLength -->
                        <!-- ngIf: reqForBusinessTaxIDFornozero -->

                        <!-- ngIf: reqForBusinessTaxID -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-size--1-of-1 slds-medium-size--3-of-6 slds-large-size--6-of-12 slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-grid_align-center" style="display: block;padding-right: 30px;margin-top: 15px;">

                            <label class="labelAboveTextBox">Responsible Party First Name*</label>
                            <input type="text" class="businessName afname ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty" id="responsibeFirstName" ng-keyup="responsibeFirstName();" ng-model="afname" style="width: 100%;">
                            <!-- ngIf: reqafname -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-size--1-of-1 slds-medium-size--3-of-6 slds-large-size--6-of-12 slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-grid_align-center" style="display: block;margin-top: 15px;padding-right: 30px;">

                            <label class="labelAboveTextBox">Responsible Party Last Name*</label>
                            <input type="text" class="businessName alname ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty" id="responsibeLastName" ng-keyup="responsibeLastName();" ng-model="alname" style="width: 100%;">
                            <!-- ngIf: reqalname -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-size--1-of-1 slds-medium-size--6-of-6 slds-large-size--12-of-12 slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-grid_align-center corpLLCSoleContainer ng-hide" style="" ng-show="soleOrCorp === 'soleproprietorship' ">
                    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-size--1-of-1 slds-medium-size--6-of-6 slds-large-size--12-of-12 slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-grid_align-center">
                        <p class="Body ng-binding"></p>
                        <div ng-hide="hideForAgent" class="slds-m-top--medium" style="width: 100%;">
                            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-size--1-of-1 slds-medium-size--6-of-6 slds-large-size--12-of-12 slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-grid_align-center soleProprietorInputDiv" style="padding-bottom: 5px;padding-top:5px;">
                                <div class="slds-size--1-of-1 slds-medium-size--3-of-6 slds-large-size--6-of-12" style="padding-right: 30px;">
                                    <label class="labelAboveTextBox">Business name*</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="sBusinessName ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-valid-maxlength ng-valid ng-valid-required" ng-model="businessName" ng-required="businessName" ng-keyup="setBusinessName(businessName)" maxlength="30" style="width: 100%;>
                                     <span ng-if=" reqsbusinessname"="">This is required
                                </div>
                                <div class="slds-size--1-of-1 slds-medium-size--3-of-6 slds-large-size--6-of-12" style="padding-right: 30px;">
                                    <label class="labelAboveTextBox">SSN*</label>
                                    <input type="password" class="ssn ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-valid ng-valid-required" ng-required="ssnId" ng-model="ssnId" ng-blur="PIEEncryptionSsn()" ng-change="Check(ssnId, 'ssn', 'ssn')" ng-class="{'vz_error': ssnId.length > 0 &amp;&amp; ssnId.length !== 9, 'noredBorder': ssnId.length === 9}" style="width: 100%;>
                                    <span ng-if=" reqssnidlen"="">SSN Length should be 9
                                    <!-- ngIf: reqssnIdlpatternDups -->
                                    <!-- ngIf: reqssnIdlpattern --> 
                                    <!-- ngIf: reqssnId -->                            </div>
                            </div>








                            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-size--1-of-1 slds-medium-size--6-of-6 slds-large-size--12-of-12 slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-grid_align-center" style="padding-top: 25px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
                                <div class="slds-size--1-of-1" style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; font-family: 'NeueHaasGroteskDisplayBold'; color: black;">
                                    Please provide the name of person responsible for the account 
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-size--1-of-1 slds-medium-size--6-of-6 slds-large-size--12-of-12 slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-grid_align-center ssnHolderNameDiv" style="padding-bottom: 5px;">
                                <div class="slds-size--1-of-1 slds-medium-size--3-of-6 slds-large-size--3-of-12" style="padding-right: 30px;">
                                    <label class="labelAboveTextBox">Responsible Party First Name*</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="fname ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty" ng-model="fname" style="width: 100%;" reqfname"="">This is required
                                </div>
                                <div class="slds-size--1-of-1 slds-medium-size--3-of-6 slds-large-size--3-of-12" style="padding-right: 30px;">
                                    <label class="labelAboveTextBox">Responsible Party Last Name*</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="lname ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty" ng-model="lname" style="width: 100%;" reqlname"="">This is required
                                </div>
                                <div class="slds-large-size--6-of-12"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-gr id_vertical-align-center slds-medium-size--6-of-6 slds-large-size--12-of-12 slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-grid_align-center" style="margin-bottom: 0px;padding-top: 15px;">
                               <label class=" labelAboveTextBox">Date of Birth*</label>
                            </div>


                             <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-medium-size--6-of-6 slds-large-size--12-of-12 slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-grid_align-center" id="ssnDOBdiv" style="padding-bottom: 5px;margin-top: 0.3%;">
                                <div class="slds-size--1-of-1 slds-medium-size--6-of-6 slds-large-size--4-of-12">
                                    <label class="labelAboveTextBox">MM/DD/YYYY</label>
                                    <input type="text" datepicker-credit-section="" class="yYYY ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" ng-model="ssnDOB" readonly="" id="creditCheckDOBY" ng-blur="PIEEncryptionDOB()" style="width: 100%;>
                                </div>                              
                                <div class=" slds-large-size--6-of-12"=""></div>
                            </div>
                             <div><!-- ngIf: reqDOB --></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-size--1-of-1 slds-medium-size--6-of-6 slds-large-size--12-of-12">
                    <button class="btn-buyF btn-primary-buyF btn-md-buyF save-btn ng-binding" ng-class="{'confirm-btn-disabled': (successCredit || hideForAgent)}" ng-click="scrollToTop(); validateCreditCheckData();" style="height: 42px;border-radius: 21px;">Proceed</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I don't see the `//iframe[@class='cPATCHEDOmniScriptCommunity']` element within the HTML you have provided. Additionally, though the larger HTML is useful can you help us with the exact `<input>` you are trying to locate?

Comment: The iframe is way above this piece of HTML. I just put the HTML of the section where I was facing the issue. Below is the exact <input> : <input type="text" class="businessName ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched" ng-model="businessName" ng-keyup="setBusinessName(businessName)" maxlength="30" style="width: 100%;">

Answer (score 0):

Try the following Xpath.

```
//input[@class='businessName ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched'][@ng-model='businessName']
```

*Edited Answer**

```
//label[@class='labelAboveTextBox'][contains(.,'Business name')]/following-sibling::input
```

---

**Updated**

---

Use WebdriverWait and elementtobeclickable and use following xpath.Since You have two similar element present and you have said class names are getting change in each automation run i have provided index option for the 1st element.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("(//label[@class='labelAboveTextBox'][contains(.,'Business name')]/following-sibling::input)[1]")));
element.sendKeys("TestData");
```

Comment: Hey KunduK, thanks for the response. But this does not serve as the solution as the class name changes frequently and you will see this error : java.lang.AssertionError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@class='businessName ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched'][@ng-model='businessName']"}

Comment: @KovidMehta : Try the Edited answer.

Comment: Which approach you want me to follow to enter the text with this xpath ? SendKeys or JSE ?

Comment: Always use SendKeys.

Comment: So it doesn't work with SendKeys ! It throws no error but it does not enters the text, which is what the main issue here is. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: Do one thing what I observe there is two elements presents.use the last xpath with (xpath)[1]